# Angular directive that binds to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Just hoping to be given a simple exmaple of a use case.

I have the following directive,

```
angular.module('aahBreakdownLocationMapModule', ['aahBreakdownLocationMapControllerModule']).directive('aahBreakdownLocationMap', [function aahBreakdownLocationMap() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'src/app/components/breakdown-location-map/breakdown-location-map.template.html',
        scope: {
            taskid: '='
        },
        controller: 'BreakdownLocationMapController',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        bindToController: true
    };
}]);
```

As `taskid` is changed by something external to this directive, how can I keep an eye on it?

Example, when `taskid` changes, i need to go off and get the current location of said task from the server, so need to call one of our APIs using the new `taskid` as an argument, i don't actually ever display `taskid` within the directive.

What is the best way to do this, as i have obviously not got `$scope.$watch` available (or at least, i don't want it available)

NB: I am using 1.3

TIA

Comment: Do you call the API inside this directive? The best way to detect change is using $watch, if it must be done inside this directive. Or you can call the API at the change source. Or have the change source $emit/$broadcast. Or have a service to manage it.

Comment: wanted to avoid using `$watch` as that is on the `$scope` and isn't that half the point of using controllerAs/bindToController

but yes I call API from within the directive as the change source doesn't have the concern of location

Comment: I'm still new to `controllerAs` so can't give much advice on that. Using $watch would be a clean approach on traditional scope controller.

Comment: "As taskid is changed by something external to this directive, how can I keep an eye on it?" Just to keep an eye on it ..why not try to $broadcast the task id change event and in your controller listen to that event. Not sure how much control you have over the task id changes. Ofcourse $watch would be straightforward and simplest way. Just another thought.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `scope.$watch`, actually. You can get the scope and then be able to `$watch` its model with a `link` function for your directive:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: …
    …
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.$watch('taskid', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            // retrieve new data
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: but i can't call a funciton/other props on `ctrl` from within the link function

Comment: Yes you can, the link function gets the controller as one of its paramaters. See the example: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate

Answer (score 0):

angulyar does not give us much choice to track changes:

You can use $watch inside contoller

```
$scope.$watch('ctrl.taskid', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        // retrieve new data
});
```

Or you need to use service which pass taskid into directive controller.

But i prefer use $watch.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of $watch accepts a function which can return the specific view model (controllerAs alias bound) property:

```
$scope.$watch(
   function() { return ctrl.taskid; },
   function(newVal, oldVal) {
       // ...
   });
```

---

**EDIT**

Yes one of the benefits of using controllerAs + bindToController is that you don't need to use $scope to manually bind up isolated scope parameters to your view model, however in terms of monitoring changes to a binding there are only two real approaches:

1. use $watch
2. monitor the change on the control changing the value in the first place, e.g. use ng-change on the input that is changing the value, and then call a callback or broadcast an event.